# Merging 2 maps variables in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have 2 map type variables in Terraform,

1st - **fqdns:**

```
fqdns_map = [
  {
    "fqdn" = "db.example.com"
  },
  {
    "fqdn" = "lb.example.com"
  },
  {
    "fqdn" = "web.example.com"
  },
]
```

2nd - **ipv4s:**

```
ipv4s_map = [
  {
    "ipv4_address" = "1.1.1.1"
  },
  {
    "ipv4_address" = "2.2.2.2"
  },
  {
    "ipv4_address" = "3.3.3.3"
  },
]
```

And I want to merge it to one variable, like this:

```
merged_map = [
  {
    "fqdn" = "db.example.com",
    "ipv4_address" = "1.1.1.1"
  },
  {
    "fqdn" = "lb.example.com",
    "ipv4_address" = "2.2.2.2"
  },
  {
    "fqdn" = "web.example.com",
    "ipv4_address" = "3.3.3.3"
  }
]
```

but it's not works for me:

I tryed to use [merge()](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge) function,

```
locals {
  merged_map = merge(local.fqdns_map), local.ipv4s_map)
}
```

and get error:
`all to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "tuple".`

then i tried convert my variables to map with [tomap()](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/map) function:

```
locals {
  merged_map = merge(tomap(local.fqdns_map), tomap(local.ipv4s_map))
}
```

and get other error:
`Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert tuple to map of any single type.`

How i can merge it? Thanks!

Comment: the `ipv4s_map` and `fqdns_map` are not map but tuple (you can see that are enclosed by `[]` and not `{}`. But also if you will convert into map them, the result of this merge is not what you expect.
The number of elements in each variable is always the same? Or is possible that `ipv4s ` are more than `fqdns` and viceversa?

Comment: Yep, the number of elements in each variable is always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit tricky but:

##### 1. Change `ipv4s_map` and `fqdns_map` from SET to LIST.

If are variables simply define them as list, as the follow:

```
variable "fqdns_map" {
  type = list(map(string))
  default = [ 
  {
    "fqdn" = "db.example.com"
  },
  {
    "fqdn" = "lb.example.com"
  },
  {
    "fqdn" = "web.example.com"
  },
] 
}

variable "ipv4s_map" {
  type = list(map(string))
  default = [ 
  {
    "ipv4_address" = "1.1.1.1"
  },
  {
    "ipv4_address" = "2.2.2.2"
  },
  {
    "ipv4_address" = "3.3.3.3"
  },
] 
}
```

If are generated by some output you can use the `tolist()` built-in function

##### 2. Use multiple nested functions to obtain the result

With the `for cycle` you iterate on one of the list, for each element of the list you use the `merge function` to merge the two map, retrieving the second one using the `index function` (supposing the elements are in order)

```
locals {
    merged_map = [ for fqdns in var.fqdns_map : merge(fqdns, var.ipv4s_map[index(var.fqdns_map, fqdns)])]
}
```

The result is this, I tested all in terraform console

```
[
  tomap({
    "fqdn" = "db.example.com"
    "ipv4_address" = "1.1.1.1"
  }),
  tomap({
    "fqdn" = "lb.example.com"
    "ipv4_address" = "2.2.2.2"
  }),
  tomap({
    "fqdn" = "web.example.com"
    "ipv4_address" = "3.3.3.3"
  }),
]
```

PS: Answer human generated :)